# How to deal the response message one by one?

Tags: clone, response, wso2

I need to send a request to multiple different addresses. Some success, some maybe return an error, and I need write log for this response. I think I need
deal the response message one by one. How to do this in outsequence.
My service config is:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="CloneTest" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <clone id="12345">
            <target>
               <endpoint>
                  <address uri="address1" format="pox" />
               </endpoint>
            </target>
            <target>
               <endpoint>
                  <address uri="address2" format="pox" />
               </endpoint>
            </target>
            <target>
               <endpoint>
                  <address uri="address3" format="pox" />
               </endpoint>
            </target>
         </clone>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full" />
         <send />
      </outSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the following method. First create three endpoints namely "ep1", "ep2" and "ep3" in ESB, corresponding to the three destinations to which you want to send the cloned request. Then refer to those endpoints inside your proxy service configuration as shown below.

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="CloneTest" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <clone id="12345">
            <target endpoint="ep1">
            <target endpoint="ep2">
            <target endpoint="ep3">
         </clone>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full" />
         <send />
      </outSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>
```